# Xcode App Delegate

Tags: xcode, swift3, appdelegate, crashlytics

I am editing a project that was passed down to me. I am trying to install Crashlytics to see crashes. However, the installation requires me to edit the AppDelegate.swift file... The project does not contain an app delegate file!

I tried adding an appDelegate.swift file manually, but when I tried to print("Hello"), it was never called.

1) Is there a way to check for an app delegate.swift

2) How do I reconnect an appdelegate?

Comment: Surely knowing what an app delegate is would be a prerequisite for doing iOS programming?

Comment: My question does not ask what an app delegate is.. I am asking for possible solutions as to how it can be replaced

Comment: Just give the app a delegate, if it doesn't already have one. But I hardly see how it can lack one. Where is `@UIApplicationMain`?

Comment: The questioner just wants to know how to incorporate Crashlytics into an app.

Comment: @OwenHartnett I'm starting to think it's not an app at all, and that's the whole problem.

Comment: The app does run.. if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Well, that's good! So log `type(of: UIApplication.shared.delegate!)` and now you'll know the name of app delegate class.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for. Apparently the appDelegate.swift file I manually created was working, but the print function was never firing.

Comment: I'm not sure I believe that. Why not put a breakpoint? You have the world's greatest debugger: debug. If you don't pause at your breakpoint, your code is not running. [Another idea: change the declared name of your app delegate class and do the log again. If the log output doesn't change, your app delegate class is not the app delegate we're looking for.]

Answer (score 1):

Do a global search on `@UIApplicationMain`. The class marked with that attribute is the app delegate.

Either that or look for a call in C to `UIApplicationMain`; that call contains the name of the app delegate class.

Another approach: run the app with this line somewhere that you know actually will get executed:

```
print(type(of: UIApplication.shared.delegate!))
```

Now you'll know the name of the app delegate class.

Comment: I have done that. There is no @UIApplicationMain attribute for any class.

Comment: Then how does the app launch? An app without a `@UIApplicationMain` attribute or a `UIApplicationMain` function call (in a _main_ file) cannot launch! If you have neither of those things, that explains the whole problem: whatever you have the code to _is not an app_.

Comment: I believe I have found the app delegate.. inside my Alamofire -> Example -> source.. But print functions are not being called. Should the print functions execute?

Comment: I doubt that what you've found is "the app delegate" for this project. It's just Alamofire example. I have no idea what you've got but I don't think it's an app.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the writer of the code used some third party library which handles the appDelegate functions.  In that case, they may have some api or callback which allows you to get called during certain methods of the appDelegate class.  Check the documentation for the particular library used.  Some of the most common are PhoneGap, Cordova, etc.

Comment: There is a reference to an appDelegate in alamofire. However, when I edit the appDelegate in the alamofire location, nothing is changed. Is it possible the third party library handles the app delegate outside of the project (from its own library that is unaccessible?) Is there a possible solution to edit this?

Comment: alamofire is a networking library.  You probably have another library or framework in use that has wrapped the appDelegate.  It should provide you with some method of getting called from various calls in the appDelegate code, the most important method being at startup.  You have to identify which library you're using, and look through it's documentation.